# MS Access 2013 Dlookup String Criteria issue

Tags: ms-access, vba

It seems this problem should have a rather simplistic solution. When trying to run the dlookup for ID, I return a null value when using the RequestNum string. RequestNum is simply an AutoNumber. RequestNum does write to the popup form that is opening up on its own. Also, if i replace RequestNum with the actual number in the field I get the desired returned result. The only help I've been able to find online is that most people did not use `'" & stringhere & "'` though I obviously am. Any ideas? I'll be happy to supply any additional details if needed. Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub lst_AdminDate1_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim IDx As String
    Dim RequestNum As String
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Administrative_LeaveCalendar_Detail"
    RequestNum = Me.lst_AdminDate1.Column(2)
    IDx = DLookup("[ID]", "TimeOffCalendar", "[RequestNumber] = '" & RequestNum & "'")
    [Forms]![Administrative_LeaveCalendar_Detail]![txtAdminDateDetail_RN] = RequestNum
    [Forms]![Administrative_LeaveCalendar_Detail]![txtAdminDateDetail_ID] = IDx
    End Sub
```

Comment: If RequestNum is an autonumber, then it's a long integer by default. Adjust the data type in your dimension and remove the single quotes from the Dlookup WHERE argument and it should work. If not, what does `debug.print Me.lst_AdminDate1.Column(2)` yield? If it's the correct ID, then try coercing to a long int with `RequestNum = Clng(Me.lst_AdminDate1.Column(2)`. If it isn't the correct ID, are you referencing the correct column? `.Column` is zero-indexed, so try `.Column(1)`.

Comment: Removing single quotes and adding IDx as variant took care of the issue. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What may confuse you is, that a listbox always returns strings even if the value was a number and is supposed to be used as such. Also, DLookup may return *Null*.

Thus, if `[RequestNumber]` is a Long (which is should be):

```
Private Sub lst_AdminDate1_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim IDx As Variant
    Dim RequestNum As String

    DoCmd.OpenForm "Administrative_LeaveCalendar_Detail"
    RequestNum = Me.lst_AdminDate1.Column(2)
    IDx = DLookup("[ID]", "TimeOffCalendar", "[RequestNumber] = " & RequestNum & "")
    [Forms]![Administrative_LeaveCalendar_Detail]![txtAdminDateDetail_RN] = RequestNum
    [Forms]![Administrative_LeaveCalendar_Detail]![txtAdminDateDetail_ID] = IDx

End Sub
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks for the answer! Learned something new about trying to use autonumber as a string also.